# How to Determine the input and output values of stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures, parameter

I have hundreds of SPs and I would like to find out:

- input parameters with type
- output fields with type (not output parameters)

Of course I could manually go through each one and write it down but where is the fun in that...No, literally where IS the fun in that :)

Can this be done or does Sql Management Studio 2008 R2 have this capability already?

I do not even know where to start so any answer is acceptable.

Edit for enhancment of question:
If we look at it as 2 different tasks, could we accomplish this easier. Even using reflection on the client side. (A quick and dirty console app would suffice.)

Comment: What do you mean "output fields"? Are you talking about output parameters or the columns in the result set(s)?

Comment: What is the difference? Can I have both at the same time as well?  All I really care is what type of data I will be getting back. I am new to the terminology. I thought columns are also known as fields. But as Marian states, I  meant "columns in the result set". :)

Comment: columns and fields **are** pretty synonymous. Reason for the question was because you explicitly mentioned input parameters so wasn't sure whether you had meant to refer to output parameters there. There isn't currently a good way of getting the column list (and there may be more than one result set or its shape can vary according to procedural code in the proc). Visual Studio does it by `SET FMTONLY ON;` and executing the stored procedure. SQL Server 2012 has some additional functions that will help here.

Comment: What are output parameters?

Comment: Parameters decorated with the `output` keyword that can be assigned to in the proc and the value retrieved by the stored procedure caller. Useful when you want to pass back scalar values rather than rows of data. They are actually input/output parameters in that they can also be used to pass values into the procedure.

Comment: So just like an 'out' variable in C# formal parameter declaration.

Comment: More like a `ref` parameter but not exactly that either. See [Parameter Passing Semantics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/06/09/624531.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do that using the system view [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173796.aspx).
You'll have there what you need.

It "returns one row for each parameter of a user-defined function or stored procedure that can be accessed by the current user in the current database. For functions, this view also returns one row with return value information."

PS: if the answer to Martin's question is "columns in the result set", then ignore my answer, it is only for the parameters of the procedures, not for any result.

Answer (score 4):

For input and output parameters, you can look at [`sys.parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176074.aspx), [`sys.procedures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188737.aspx) and [`sys.types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188021.aspx). Here is a procedure with various input/output parameters, alias types and even a TVP (2008+ only):

```
USE [tempdb];
GO

CREATE TYPE dbo.TVPType AS TABLE(id INT);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foobar
    @a INT,
    @b SYSNAME = N'foo',
    @c DATETIME = NULL,
    @d dbo.TVPType READONLY,
    @e NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @f INT OUTPUT,
    @g INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @f = COUNT(*) FROM sys.objects;
END
GO
```

And here is a query to pull this information from `sys.parameters`, `sys.procedures` and `sys.types`:

```
SELECT 
    s = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.[object_id])),
    o = QUOTENAME(p.name),
    p = pr.name, 
    t1.name,
    pr.max_length, 
    pr.[precision], 
    pr.scale, 
    pr.is_output,
    pr.is_readonly
FROM sys.procedures AS p
INNER JOIN sys.parameters AS pr
ON p.[object_id] = pr.[object_id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.types AS t1 
ON (pr.system_type_id = t1.system_type_id)
AND (pr.system_type_id <> t1.system_type_id
OR pr.user_type_id = t1.user_type_id)
WHERE p.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.foobar')
ORDER BY pr.parameter_id;
```

Results:

```
s       o           p   name    max_length  [precision]  scale  is_output  is_readonly
-----   ----------  --- -------- ---------  -----------  -----  ---------  -----------
[dbo]   [foobar]    @a  int              4           10      0          0            0
[dbo]   [foobar]    @b  sysname        256            0      0          0            0
[dbo]   [foobar]    @c  datetime         8           23      3          0            0
[dbo]   [foobar]    @d  TVPType         -1            0      0          0            1
[dbo]   [foobar]    @e  nvarchar        -1            0      0          0            0
[dbo]   [foobar]    @f  int              4           10      0          1            0
[dbo]   [foobar]    @g  int              4           10      0          1            0
```

Obviously you need to do some massaging to get those values to look like real data types. Cut a nvarchar's max_length in half, for example, unless it's -1, in which case it needs to get swapped out with `MAX`. For decimal, numeric etc., add the precision and scale appropriately. If you are using TVPs you probably want to grab the schema using `SCHEMA_NAME` for those types. Etc. etc.

Unfortunately, there is no way except brute force parsing the procedure body (and even that is not trivial without serious ninja RegEx skills) to determine if the parameter is nullable, or whether it has a default value, and what the default value is. This information is simply not stored in the metadata - while there are `has_default_value` and `default_value` columns in `sys.parameters`, they are only ever non-`NULL` or non-zero for CLR procedures. [I've been complaining about this since 2006](http://web.archive.org/web/20130726131248/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=234143), but we have yet to see any advancements in this area. I did start a project called [ParamParser](https://github.com/AaronBertrand/ParamParser) that uses PowerShell to parse procedure and function bodies for their parameters, data types, and default values; feel free to try it out. Here's the output for the above procedure:

> [image]

For result sets, Martin is quite right - there isn't a robust way to figure out what a result will consist of except using [`SET FMTONLY ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx). There are some peculiar bugs with this one, so I would stay away from it. A popular kludge is to use [`OPENQUERY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) with a "loopback" [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279%28SQL.110%29.aspx), select the results into a #temp table, but this only works if the procedure has exactly one resultset. A good example exists in one of Martin's previous answers:

- [What's the easiest way to create a temp table in SQL Server that can hold the result of a stored procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12739/whats-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-temp-table-in-sql-server-that-can-hold-the-re)

Once you've put the output into the #temp table, you can execute:

```
EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_help N'#tablename';
```

This will output, among other things, a list of column names and their data types. While this will be a tedious process to perform for hundreds of stored procedures, I do have ideas about how to automate it so if this seems like an interesting solution to you please let me know and I can expand my answer.

Martin also alluded to new functionality in SQL Server 2012 that will make this a *lot* easier (but it is still limited to the first resultset of a stored procedure). You can see more details about that in my answer to the same question above.

For return values, I don't know of any way to get those from the metadata (and they [shouldn't be used for data anyway](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output)).

Comment: Thank you for writing and explaining things. Not knowing what result sests are, is it a dataset with multiple datatables?

Comment: The result set from the `SELECT` query up top? Did you run it (just changing the name of the procedure to search for)? It's a single resultset containing a row for per parameter (it will only become a "datatable" if you consume it in .NET and make it so).

Comment: All I really need is a quick way to initially document our SPs and determine if any are returning duplicate dataset/scalars. I do not believe that we have only a few that return multiple datatables in a dataset.

I already have exported the inputparameters to our SPs and functions to an excel spreadsheet but have not yet got the resulting datasets.

I do like the idea of automating that you mentioned and I have no problem of massaging data. I was thinking about writing a program to get the list of SP and functions and passing each into a query to generate a list of input parameters and using

Comment: reflection on the resulting dataset to get the column names and data types.

I think I might just try out your SQL query to generate the output and then massage it on a second pass.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Sorry, but as I suggested, there really isn't a way to detect duplicates in the result sets without knowing the range of input values for the procedures and running them.

Comment: When I say duplicates, I mean I want to compare the result of one SP with the results of another SP to see if they are returning the same columns, not the same datarows.
The input parameters should tell me what datarows are returned if 2 SP have the same return.

The comparison of datarow would be done pain stakenly via code/peer review. :)

Currently I just want to create a header that documents the input and return results of the SP so we do not need to look at the SP constantly.